# Select i Inside a div jQuery

Tags: php, jquery, html, font-awesome

I have a div with another div inside it containing an element i - a font awesome icon.

```
<div id="my-div-thispageme">
    <a href="/anotherpage" class="div-menu" title="Edit">
        <div>
            <img style="vertical-align:middle;" src="/images/icon_pngs/icon.png" height="40px" width="40px">
            Page Title <i id="settingsico" class="fa fa-cog fa-lg"></i>&nbsp;
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

I have had no luck adding a class 'fa-spin' to the i element (with id settingsico) with jQuery.

I have tried variants of both:

```
$("#my-div-thispageme").mouseover(function() {
    $("#my-div-thispageme a div i").addClass("fa-spin");
});
```

and

```
$("#my-div-thispageme").mouseover(function() {
    $("#settingsico").addClass("fa-spin");
});
```

but always get an error of

```
"Cannot read property 'addClass' of null"
```

[**Here is a JSFiddle - though I can't get the font-awesome icon to render!**](http://jsfiddle.net/n9KTx/1/)

Comment: Have you tried adding the mouseover to the icon container?  `$('#my-div-thispageme > div').mouseover(function() {`?

Comment: Can you create a simple jsfiddle.

Comment: In your jsfiddle, it seems to work properly. But jsfiddle.net includes jQuery itself. Are you sure you are actually including a proper version of jQuery?

Comment: I have added <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js" ></script> to this page, I am getting strange occurrences now.

Comment: The solution was to set the jquery:
$("#my-div-thispageme").mouseover(function() {
    $("#settingsico").addClass("fa-spin");
    });
remove the div, include <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js" ></script> in the same document and to clear chrome's cache

Thank You to Everybody who contributed!!

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your top-level `div` element is this: `<div id="my-div">`

However, you are using the selector `#my-div-thispageme`.

Do you mean to use the selector `#my-div`?

If so, it should be as simple as:

```
$("#my-div").mouseover(function() {
    $("#settingsico").addClass("fa-spin");
});
```

### UPDATE

Due to the error you're getting, it appears that your code thinks the DOM element doesn't exist. This leads me to think that maybe you are calling your code before the DOM has loaded, or that you have created some element dynamically.

If it is the first case, make sure that you either wrap all your jQuery code inside this:

```
$(function() {
    // your code here
});
```

Or, make sure all your code is at **the end of the `body`**.

This first is equivalent to `$(document).ready()`, and the second waits until the DOM tree has been created for executing any code.

Comment: Edited my post - that isn't the problem - type error on my part as I was trying to simplify ids for ease of reading and missed them. Apologies!

Comment: I have moved the script to the end of the document and updated it like so: 
<script type="text/javascript">
  $( document ).ready(function () {
   $("#my-div-thispageme").mouseover(function() {
    $("#settingsico").addClass("fa-spin");
    });
   });
</script>
I now get: "cannot read property 'mouseover' of null" :S

Comment: @h4ng4r18, Make a jsfiddle or post all of your code. Hard to isolate the problem without seeing everything.

Comment: I have attempted to above